# Bootstrap 4 Carousel not sliding

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the bootstrap carousel, however is doesn't want to slide.

My current code is:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../../../assets/foto-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../../../assets/foto-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../../../assets/foto-2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

in my index.html i have:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: How do You import bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes i did, added it to the post

Comment: JavaScript is missing

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Import it using `styles.css` or `.scss`

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed it, no clue how i could've missed that

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to import JS. Thanks Boss COTIGA:

JavaScript is missing getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction